# How to make text overflow with floats

Tags: html, css

I have problem with overflow text on responsive layout with text on the left and div with buttons on the right. I don't want to break row.
[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/En83R/106/)
(i don't know sizes of div right and div left, only container)
This is not working example and what I want to receive is.
[image]

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
}
.left{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
}
.right{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span class="left">text</span>
<div class="right"> Testing text  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because you have no max width for the `.left` element, so it has nothing to overflow.

Comment: Try setting the `.left` and `.right` to have percentage-based widths?

Comment: Please check out this example I created based on your work: http://jsfiddle.net/6fxocnjs/ I think it solves your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution #1: With flexbox

1) On the container element: Add `display: flex;` and `white-space: nowrap;`

2) On the right element: Add `flex:1` for it to grow to take up the remaining space.

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.left{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red; /* uncomment to see what's going on */
}
.right{
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red; /* uncomment to see what's going on */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span class="left">left text</span>
<div class="right"> Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text  </div>
 
</div>
</div>
```

### [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/WoWEda?editors=1100#0) (resize to see the effect)

---

### Solution #2: With block formatting contexts

1) Change the markup to swap the left and right elements

2) On the left element:

- replace `float: left` with `overflow: hidden` to create a new block formatting context (this causes the left element to take up the remaining width)
- add `display:block`

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
}
.left{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  //border: 1px solid red; /* uncomment to see what's going on */
  display: block;
}
.right{
  float:right;
  //border: 1px solid red; /* uncomment to see what's going on */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="right"> Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text  </div>
 <span class="left">left text</span>
</div>
</div>
```

### [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QGPMqJ) (resize to see the effect)

Comment: @D4nC00per I have added an additional (flexbox) solution :)

Comment: Not sure what that achieves. You just hide the left content on smaller screens.

Comment: @D4nC00per both solutions achieve what the OP wants to do - without added fixed widths on any of the elements

Answer (score 1):

Within your CSS, you need to set a fixed width for your elements, `.right` and `.left`.

Try this:

```
.left{
  width: 10%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.right{
  width: 90%;
  float: right;
}
```

and if you want to make it extra beautiful, add some padding to the right of `.left`:

```
.left{
  width: 10%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px; 
}
```

just make sure you account for it on `.right` using calc

```
.right{
  width: calc(90% - 5px);
  float: right;
}
```

(just so that the text doesn't collide)

Hope it helps :-)